# Turtlebot Rviz "Status: Warning"

Tags: rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I am trying to visualize data coming from my turtlebot kinect with a point cloud, there is a bar underneath it that says "Status:Waring" in yellow. What does this mean?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11172/turtlebot-rviz-%22status:-warning%22/) by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Click the little "+" button next to it to get more details.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-12-05**:
OK, I would think that would be the case yes. But, would you have a suggestion why a kinect wouldn't be publishing data?

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-11**:
No data is being published by the kinect

**Comment by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on 2011-09-11**:
What does it mean if the topic is "No messages received"?